# Import a node module in a content script of a Chrome extension (Vite and react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am trying to import the axe-core package into my content script so that I can do axe. run in a web context.

I am sending message to content script using chrome.scripting API

**I have downloaded axe.min.js and placed it inside the assets folder.**

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  async function (request, _, sendResponse) {

    console.log('On Message');

    if (request.message === "getDOM") {
      try {
        console.log('REQUEST FOUND')

        const src = chrome.runtime.getURL("src/assets/runAxe.js");
        const axeMain = await import(src);
         
        axeMain.runAxe()
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR FOUND ON MESSAGE');
        console.log(e);
      }
     
       sendResponse({ response: 'Hello' });
    }

    
  }
);
```

**src/assets/runAxe.js**

```
import {axe} from './axe.min.js'
export default async function runAxe() {
    const r = await axe.run();

    console.log('==== Results in runAxe')
    console.log(r);
    
}
```

**manifest.json** (part of manifest)

```
 "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "./src/chrome/content_script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
   
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "resources": [
            "src/assets/*",
            "src/assets/axe-core/*"
        ]
      }],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
```

Trying to make the axe-core package available on the content script

Comment: You should define a separate vite entry for runAxe.js, I don't know though, refer to the documentation.